# How to use service inside a ng-switch?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to ng-switch a service that I injected inside the controller that is used inside the scope. But it's not working. Not even sure if this is possible.

Here is an example:

```
<div ng-switch="wpService.user.logged" ng-controller="AccountCtrl as account">

    <div class="row" ng-switch-when="false">
        Not logged in
    </div>

    <div class="row" ng-switch-when="true">
        Logged in
    </div>
</div>
```

The wpService is injected inside the AccountCtrl and the wpService.user.logged returns a false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix `Account` to the service, since that is how you are defining the scope.

```
<div ng-switch="account.wpService.user.logged" ng-controller="AccountCtrl as account">

    <div class="row" ng-switch-when="false">
        Not logged in
    </div>

    <div class="row" ng-switch-when="true">
        Logged in
    </div>
</div>
```

inside your controller do

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function(wpService){
    var this = vm;
    vm.wpService = wpService;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible, but you have to add the service to your `$scope`.

```
.controller('AccountCtrl', function($scope, wpService){
    $scope.wpService = wpService;
}
```